# clicks time counter

Tags: javascript, counter

I would like to make a js which counts the time between two clicks.

I would like to click on a page point anywhere and then click to a button and the timer will count milliseconds.

I am trying something like this but counts the time from loadind the page until click the link.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function onClickCheck() 
   {
       var timeNow = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
       alert(timeNow);
   }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If `var timeNow` is null or 0, then set it
2. if `var timeNow` is not null and greater than 0, calculate the difference.
3. Only call the method, and set the var on button/mouse clicks

Script would be

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    function CountBegin() { var begin=new Date().getTime(); }
    function onClickCheck() { var timeNow = new Date().getTime(); alert(timeNow-begin); } 
 </script>
```

and then

```
<body onMouseClick="CountBegin();"> 
<a href="http://" onClick="onClickCheck();">click </a>
```

Comment: I am sorry I am new in javascript and I don't understand.
Something like that ?

<script type='text/javascript'>
   
    function CountBegin()
 {
     var begin=0; 
 }
 
   function onClickCheck() 
   {
       var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    alert(timeNow-begin);
   }
</script>

and then

<body onMouseClick="CountBegin();">

<a href="http://" onClick="onClickCheck();">click </a>

Comment: Thanks a lot again!
I would like to ask you and something else

the value I take as result is 1321089811175
what is this amount ? I think that it is not miliseconds

Comment: its the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch (jan 1st 1970).